# Remove everything from Byobu status bar

Tags: byobu

By default, the Byobu status bar contains tons of information about the distribution, updates, CPU, etc.

I want to remove all of that.

I want to only see the "tabs" of my open terminals (and the current terminal, of course).

How to do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Type `byobu-quiet`: *Silence all of Byobu's status indicators and eliminate the hardstatus line*
2. Append these lines to `~/.byobu/profile.tmux`:

   ```
   BYOBU_DATE=""  
   BYOBU_TIME=""
   ```
3. Close and start byobu.

Tested on Ubuntu 2019.04. It survives a reboot, too.